# How to change rightIcon conditionally in List Item. I am using react-native elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am new to react-native and I am using react-native elements library .I have tried calling a function as below inside rightIcon but it's not rendering the rightIcon

```
  renderItem = ({item}) => (
    console.log('renderItem', item),
    (
      <ListItem
        title={item.name}
        subtitle={<Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{item.subtitle}</Text>}
        leftIcon={<Image source={item.avatar_url} />}
        rightIcon={
          // name: 'ios-arrow-forward',
          // type: 'ionicon',
          () => this.changeIcon(item)
        }
        onPress={this.navigateToScreen(item.route)}
      />
    )
  );
```

```
  changeIcon = item => {
    console.log('changeItem', item);
    if (item.subtitle != 'Completed')
      return <Image source={require('../../../assets/icons/menu.png')} />;
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`() => this.changeIcon(item)` returns a function reference but `ListItem` expects a component.

try

`rightIcon={this.changeIcon(item)}`